# debugger Spyder stuck in SciPy SLSQP

Tags: debugging, spyder, scipy-optimize

When not running the debugger in Spyder I have no problem, but when I try to reach a breakpoint with Debug file (ctrl+f5) it stops here, before the breakpoint:

```
ipdb> > c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\slsqp.py(313)_minimize_slsqp()
    311     # meq, mieq: number of equality and inequality constraints
    312     meq = sum(map(len, [atleast_1d(c['fun'](x, *c['args']))
1-> 313               for c in cons['eq']]))
    314     mieq = sum(map(len, [atleast_1d(c['fun'](x, *c['args']))
    315                for c in cons['ineq']]))
```

While I don't have any breakpoint there, and I don't get any error message. When trying to continue to the next breakpoint with ctrl+f12 I and up at exactly the same place, which is probably due to my iteration. What's going wrong?